# python file open fetches wrapper string rather than file code

Tags: python

i'm to open a file, yet everytime i open it and print the contents, its prints an 84 length string which is
`<io.TextIOWrapper name = 'C:\\DOWNLOADS\\COMMISSIONS.TXT' mode='rt' encoding='utf-8'>`

```py
import os
FILE_OBJECT = open('C:\DOWNLOADS\COMMISSIONS.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
print(str(FILE_OBJECT))
FILE_TEXT = str(FILE_OBJECT)
FILE_INDEX = len(FILE_TEXT)
FILE_LINE = 'C:\DOWNLOADS\\'
while (FILE_INDEX != 0):
    if (FILE_TEXT[FILE_INDEX - 1] == ' '):
        FILE_LINE = FILE_LINE + str('\\')
        print(FILE_LINE)
        FILE_INDEX = FILE_INDEX - 1
    else:
        FILE_LINE = str(FILE_TEXT[FILE_INDEX - 1]) + FILE_LINE
        FILE_INDEX = FILE_INDEX - 1
    if (FILE_TEXT[FILE_INDEX - 1] == '\n'):
        os.makedirs(FILE_LINE)
        print(FILE_LINE)
        FILE_LINE = 'c:\\DOWNLOADS\\'
        FILE_INDEX =
FILE_INDEX - 1
print('close')
FILE_OBJECT.close()
```

Comment: `FILE_TEXT = str(FILE_OBJECT)` is going to give you just that ... presumably you want `FILE_TEXT = FILE_OBJECT.read()` which would give you the actual file contents ... also all these ALL_CAPS variable names are by convention constants, not variables... you should probably think about following standard coding standards with regards to variable/function names (your future co-workers will thank you... or at least want to hurt you less)

Answer (score 0):

You're currently not printing the file content, you're printing the file itself which is an object. You need to get the file content with the `read()` method of that object.

```
import os

file_object = open('./path/to/example.txt')
file_content = file_object.read()

print(f"File object: {file_object}\nFile content: {file_content}")

file_object.close()
```

If you use "str()", at any point to get the file contents you've not done it right, the correct way to get it already outputs as a string.

Good luck!